# C vulnerabilities

Tags: c, security, c-strings

I was reading about the vulnerabilities in strings in C and then I came across this code. Could anyone give me an explanation why this is vulnerable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check array indexing.

Comment: `strcpy` copies `strlen + 1` characters. What happens when `strlen(str) == MAXSIZE`?

Comment: Writing beyond the bounds of an array is undefined behavior.  Look at your `while` loop.  Do you think that `j` will always be between `0` and `9`?  And as mentioned, your `strcpy` call is unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[MAXSIZE];
if (strlen(str) > MAXSIZE)
    return;
strcpy(buf, str);
```

This code incorrectly check for maximum length. C string have a nul at the end of the string to mark the end of the string. strcpy() will copy it. To accomodate for this nul, the test must be:

```
if (strlen(str) >= MAXSIZE)
```

The code below is also incorrect.
int i[10];
int j = 0;

```
while (j < 10000){
    i[j] = 5;                
    ++j;
}
```

This code will overwrite the data in memory after the 10 integers of array i. This will create an undefined behavior, probably a crash but maybe something more subtle...